# p5.js: random() function in rotateX() draws vector at multiple angles instead of just one

Tags: rotation, p5.js

I created the following for loop in setup() to push() random vectors and thetas to individual arrays.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
   randomVector = createVector(
       random(-500, 500),
       random(-800, 0),
       random(-500, 500)
   );

   vectorLocations.push(randomVector);
   randomTheta = random(0, 360);
   vectorThetas.push(randomTheta);
}
```

I then created a function to loop over these arrays and draw multiple planes with one specific random location and one specific random rotation:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vectorThetas.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < vectorLocations.length; j++) {
      var conf = vectorLocations[j];
      var angle = vectorThetas[i];
      push();
      translate(conf);
      rotateX(angle);
      normalMaterial();
      plane(30, 30);
      pop();
      angle += 20;
   }
}
```

When I draw the above function, each individual plane is drawn at a single random location but at several different rotations, instead of just one. The angle addition for a rotating animation therefore does not work either.

I've tried different combinations of push() and pop() but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You are using nested for loops when you should just be using a single for loop. Since both the position and angle for each plane reside at the same location in both the `vectorLocations` and the `vectorThetas` arrays, you can use a single variable `i`. Just to be safe I've combined the checks to make sure `i` is less than the length of both arrays.

The change to each angle was not working because you were modifying the value of the local variable `angle` rather than updating the values stored in the array.

```js
let vectorLocations = [];
let vectorThetas = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
    randomVector = createVector(
      random(-500, 500),
      random(-800, 0),
      random(-500, 500)
    );

    vectorLocations.push(randomVector);
    randomTheta = random(0, 360);
    vectorThetas.push(randomTheta);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  orbitControl(4, 2, 0.1);
  for (let i = 0; i < vectorThetas.length && i < vectorLocations.length; i++) {
      let conf = vectorLocations[i];
      let angle = vectorThetas[i];
      push();
      translate(conf);
      rotateX(angle);
      normalMaterial();
      plane(30, 30);
      pop();
      vectorThetas[i] += 10;
  }
}
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```